# What are Complex Types?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, complextype

I am Creating a Application in MVC3 . I am Using Entity Framework as ORM. Can anyone tell me What are the Complex Types in ENtity Framework ?
i am not Getting what is Complex Type .

Comment: How did you manage it to *not* find an answer by a simple Google search? Like this: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/28/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I picked this simple definition from EntityFramework book. (Definition is in context with EF code first)

Complex Types Convention
When Code First discovers a class definition where a primary key cannot be inferred, and no primary key is registered through data annotations or the fluent API, then the type is automatically registered as a complex type. Complex type detection also requires that the type does not have properties that reference entity types and is not referenced from a collection property on another type. Given the following class definitions Code First would infer that Details is a complex type because it has no primary key.

```
public partial class OnsiteCourse : Course
{
    public OnsiteCourse()
    {
        Details = new Details();
    }

    public Details Details { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public System.DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Days { get; set; }
}
```

Rest you can easily find out googling about EF complex types, As suggested by @Slauma.

Comment: Complex types are a way to encapsulate a set of entity’s properties inside a
structure which isn’t an entity. You use them to organize properties into
structures that make your design more understandable. For example, you
can have a Customer entity which has properties that make an address.
You can arrange these properties in a Address complex type. Complex types are a conceptual entities types.

To Read More about Complex Type Click me - http://softmindit.blogspot.in/p/mvc-is-framework-methodology-that.html